# Find all hrefs that start with ' '

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find all hrefs that are apart of an 'a' element that start with 'start/of/link'.
This is what I tried after seeing this as an answer to someone else's similar question, but it did not work.

```
hrefs = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/start/of/link'))
```

I don't get an error, but when printing the hrefs variable It is empty.

Comment: Can you share URL or edit your question with HTML snippet?

Comment: try regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work like this

```py
soup.find_all('a', {"href" : re.compile('^/start/of/link')})
```